# Inside php script isn't working

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Im new to php and its developing. i'm using **codeigniter**. header tag is the only tag display there .latter part of script isn't avaliable in view page.
my login_view.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Login page </title>
</head>


<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Login</h1>
        <?php

        echo form_open();

        echo "<p> Email :";
        echo form_input('email');
        echo "</p>";

        echo "<p> password :";
        echo form_input('password');
        echo "</p>";

        echo "<p>";
        echo form_submit('login_submit','login');
        echo "</p>";

        echo form_close();
    ?>    

   </div>       

</body>
</html>
```

and its  page source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Login page </title>
</head>


<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Login</h1>
```

login.php -controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean `codeigniter`?

Comment: @itachi yes dude it is

Comment: Turn on your error reporting (`ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`). After that, let us know if anything else shows up..

Comment: post your controller.

Comment: @itachi i have posted controller. but it is nothing just call to view

Comment: @Darren where do i find that code.please

Comment: you didn't load the form helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as my CI memory goes back, you have to do like this.

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form'); //<----------- this
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to load form helper using `$this->load->helper('form');` in controller or config file for showing it. At first, check it and if still you face any problem, then post your controller.